# Perl - Insert lines after a match is found in a file

Tags: perl

I have a file with the following syntax in some_1.xyz

```
module some_1 {
INPUT PINS
OUTPUT PINS
}
```

and I want to insert APPLY DELAYS xx and APPLY LOADS ld after line module some_1 {

The following code works fine for just one file i.e., if I replace some_1.xyz to *.xyz then the script doesn't work. I tried introducing sleep(xx) but the code doesn't work for multiple files and I could not figure out why it isn't working. Any pointers is appreciated. Thanks

```
@modulename_array = `grep "module " some_1.xyz | cut -f 2 -d ' '`;
@line = `grep "module " some_1.xyz`;

chomp(@line);
chomp(@kfarray);

$i = 0;
foreach (@modulename_array) {
  print "Applying delay and load to $_.xyz $line[$i] \n";

  `perl -ni -le 'print; print "\tAPPLY DELAY xx \n \tAPPLY LOADS  ld\n" if/$line[$i]/' $_.xyz`;
  $i++;
  #sleep(3);

}
```

Comment: I have around 1500 such files into which these additional lines have to be embedded. and I'm using perl-5.8.8 on Linux.

Comment: just to note if the files you're parsing are perl you could use PPI, but that doesn't look like perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what's wrong with the easy solution?:

```
$data=`cat /the/input/file`;
$data=~s/some_1 {\n/some_1 {\nAPPLY DELAYS xx\nAPPLY LOADS ld\n/gm;
print $data;
```

Answer (score 5):

Something much simpler, in just one line using SED (in case this question is for UNIX only and when the match is a fixed value, not regular expression):

```
sed -i -e "s/<match pattern>/<match pattern>\n<new line here>/g" file.txt
```

(The options have been swapped compared to the initial response, because the first comment.)

Notice the \n is to add a new line. Regards

Comment: `sed -i -e ...` works for me but `sed -e -i ...` gives an error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: -`
I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1. I suppose the script must directly follows the `-e` arg.

Comment: I end up with an `n` character, not a new line.
man page says
"The escape sequence \n matches a newline character embedded in the pattern space.  You cannot, however, use a literal newline character in an address or in the substitute command."
(This is on OS X)

Answer (score 4):

one-liner

```
perl -pi -e '/module some_1/ and $_.="APPLY DELAY xx \nAPPLY LOADS  ld\n"' files*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text='bla bla mytext bla bla';
$find='.*mytext.*';
$repl='replacement';

$text=~ s/($find)/$1$repl/g;
```

***$1 is basically your match and you can use it when you make the replacement, either before or after your $repl string. )))***

EASY

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your code isn't working, but I have trouble following your use of Perl inside backticks inside Perl.  This is untested, but should work.  I suggest you also "use strict;" and "use warnings;".

```
my @files = ("some_1.xyz", "some_2.xyz", ... );
for my $file in ( @files )
{
    my $outfile = $file + ".tmp";
    open( my $ins, "<", $file ) or die("can't open " . $file . " for reading: " . $!);
    open( my $outs, ">", $outfile ) 
        or die("can't open " . $outfile . " for writing: " . $!);
    while ( my $line = <$ins> )
    {
        print { $outs } $line;
        if ( $line =~ m/^module\s+/ )
        {
             print { $outs } "\tAPPLY DELAY xx\n\tAPPLY LOADS ld\n";
        }
    }
    rename( $outfile, $file );
}
```

Comment: `use warnings` and `use strict` are missing, `/module /` -> `/^module\s+/`, `die("...")` -> `die "can't open $filenane: $?"` and it would be about right, considering that no OS/platform was mentioned in the question. PS line with `my $outfile = ...` is missing the semicolon.

Comment: PS line with open($outfile) is missing the semicolon

Comment: The open outfile line has a semicolon, it's just on the next line.