# How to append and the line once the matched pattern is found

Tags: perl

I want to search the string in a file and if the search string is found 
then I want to replace the three line based on value in curly braces.

I was going through one of solution from stack overflow

[Perl - Insert lines after a match is found in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422268/perl-insert-lines-after-a-match-)
    is-found-in-a-file

But the things are not working for me 
input_file:

```
abcdef1{3} { 0x55, 0x55, 0x55 }
abcdef2{2} { 0x55, 0x55}
```

code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $ipfile  = 'input.txt';
open my $my_fh "<", $ipfile  or die "Couldn't open input file: $!";
while(<$my_fh>)
{
 if (/$abcdef1/)
 {
 s/abcdef1{3} {\n/abcdef1{3} {\nabcdef1 0x55\nabcdef1 0x55\nabcdef1 
 0x55\n/gm;

}
}
```

expected output:

```
abcdef1 0x55
abcdef1 0x55
abcdef1 0x55
abcdef2 0x55
abcdef2 0x55
```

Any help with explanation would be grateful.

Comment: At first glance I'd say the first two curlies `{}` in `s/abcdef1{3} {\n/…` must be escaped. Else they mean `abcdef` followed by _exactly_ three letters `1`, i.e. `abcdef111`. Try `s/abcdef1\{3\} {\n/…`.

Comment: look like its not satisfying if condition.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. You added `use strict/warnings`. Didn't you get any warnings?. I think `if (/$abcdef1/)` tries to interpolate the variable `$abcdef1`. Escape the dollar, too: `if (/\$abcdef1/)`.

Comment: Try using a regex like `/^(abcdef1)\{(\d+)\} \{(.*)\}/`, then extract the data you need from `$3`

Comment: I have tried both the approaches but not working

Comment: @sam Simply print the content of `$1` followed by each of the extracted items from `$3` to get the desired output.

Comment: i was doing this way if (/^(abcdef1)\{(\d+)\} \{(.*)\}/)
    {
   s/abcdef1{3} {\n/abcdef1{3} {\nabcdef1 0x55\nabcdef1 0x55\nabcdef1 0x55\n/gm;
      print $1;
   print $2;
   print $3;
    }

Comment: not getting desired output

Comment: You do not need the substitution. But first extract the values from `$3`. Then  do  `print "$start $_\n" for @values` where `$start` is `$1` and `@values` are the extracted values from `$3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note in [perlre](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlre.pod) and [RE.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) that using `$` and `{ ... }` have special meanings within regular expressions. You may not see output because you are missing at least one print statement. The first curly enclosure (ie: `{\d+}`) could be optional unless you want to validate the length of the series in the second enclosure.

Your loop may look something like:

```
while (<$my_fh>) {
  if (/
      ^               # beginning of line
      ([^{]+)         # the base pattern captured in $1 ("non-left curly braces")
      .*              # any number of characters
      \{\s*(.*?)\s*\} # the data section surrounded by curlies captured in $2
      $               # end of line
      /x)          # allow whitespace and comments
  {
    for my $val (split /, /, $2) {
      print "$1 $val\n";
    }
  } else {
    print;
  }
}
```

Or more tersely:

```
while (my $line = <$my_fh>) {
  if ($line =~ /^([^{]+).*\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}$/) {
    $line = '';
    $line .= "$1 $_\n" for split /, /, $2;
  }
  print $line;
}
```

The `?` in the pattern `.*?` indicates a non-greedy match. In this case, it avoids matching the whitespace next to the second right curly brace.

Comment: `[^}\s](?:[^}]*[^}\s])?` is the reliable replacement for `.*?`.

Comment: I have tried with first approach but not getting desired output.

Comment: I have tried second approach also but its not working.

Comment: @sam I updated the answer to generalize the first capture pattern

Comment: this output i am getting for above input  "abcdef1{3} { 0x55, 0x55, 0x55 }
abcdef1{3} { 0x55, 0x55, 0x55 }
abcdef2 0x55
abcdef2 0x55
abcdef2{2} { 0x55, 0x55}" one more things i need append the output in  file from the line i am reading